# Keeping Contract Address, Web3 HttpProvider and Account Address away from the DApp UI/Frontend User

Tags: dapp-development, dapps

I am building with Quorum and Web3js. As I build the DApp UI/frontend, I realised that details such as address of the node, contract address and the account address (from:) are in plain text. One just need to right click the web page and "View Page Source" and voila, the details are all there. Sure these details are also exposed to all other nodes who are on blockchain. However, what if one wants to keep these details (account address, contract address and node URL and RPC port) from the user of the DApp UI?

Sample code below:

window.web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://nathan.aw.loves.blockchain:22000"));

var contractAddress = "0xpmj28d341d1f27f1f1e989e301550de60503941";
var contractInstance = web3.eth.contract(abi).at(contractAddress);

from:"0xyt2d61dbc6fdc72c2ffa6e7d5b8198a4eb705q08"

Nathan Aw